# firebase cloud messaging Android push notification not working

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that sends that is supposed to send a push notification to users. When the notification is received by the user, the user taps on the notification and the app is opened and a url is opened in the android webview.

but my app is not receiving any notification. 
here is the code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
         private WebView webView;
         private ProgressDialog dialog;
         private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReciever;
         private final String CHANNEL_ID="notificcation";        
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
             webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
             webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                  @Override
                  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                      if(dialog.isShowing())
                         dialog.dismiss();
                  }
             });     
             mRegistrationBroadcastReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {
                  @Override
                  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                      if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.STR_PUSH)){
                          String message=intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE);
                          showNotification("MSG",message);
                      }    
                  }
             };
             onNewIntent(getIntent());
         }
         @Override
         protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
              dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
              if(intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY)!=null){
                  dialog.show();
                  dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
                  webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY));    
              }
         }    
         private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
              Intent intent =new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra(Config.STR_KEY,message);
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
              PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
              NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
              builder.setAutoCancel(true)
              .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
              .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
              .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
              .setContentTitle(title)
              .setContentText(message)
              .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

              NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
         }
         @Override
         protected void onPause() {
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever);
              super.onPause();
         }
         @Override
         protected void onResume() {
              super.onResume();
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,new IntentFilter("registration Complete"));
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,new IntentFilter(Config.STR_PUSH));
         }
    }
```

**The FirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       handleMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get(Config.STR_KEY));

    }

    private void handleMessage(String message) {
        Intent pushNotification=new Intent(Config.STR_PUSH);
        pushNotification.putExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE,message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);


    }

}
```

The Firebase Instance class

```
public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendToServer(token);

    }

    private void sendToServer(String token) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Form where you are sending the notification Firebase Console ?

Comment: From the Firebase Console

Answer (score 2):

Messages sent via the Firebase console are treated as `notification` message payloads. From your code, you're only handling `data` message payloads (`remoteMessage.getData()` which are probably null. You could include a `data` message payload along with the `notification` message contents by adding *Advanced Option* via the Firebase Console.

Also, `FirebaseInstanceIdService` has been deprecated. Proceed with using `onNewToken()` in `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Answer (score 0):

First you are using `LocalBroadcastManager` that's only registered if your MainActivity is currently in the foreground.

Secondly, what kind of message are you sending? They could be **data** or **notification** messages. If using **data** I would get rid of the LocalBroadcastManager and declare the **showNotification** method in MyFirebaseMessagingService so you can directly show the notification from there.

If you are using **notification** messages. If your app is in the background the push notification would be handled by the System Tray, and the **onMessageReceived** would only be called if your App is in the foreground.

Take a look at the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

The most significant part:

> `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> - **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
> - **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Comment: in the console, i send also the custom data, which includes the url the app will open after clicking on the notification

Comment: If you send both notification and data, then onMessageReceived will only be called if your app is on the foreground (current active app) else the system tray will handle it and display the notification according to what you set in the console.

Comment: even when the app is in foreground notification is not recieved by the emulator. genymotion

Comment: Have you connect your Android App to a FirebaseApp? Do you have the correct `.json` file? Try as I say removing the LocalBroadcastManager. Also add some logging to the onMessageReceived to check if it really arrives there